# How to run a pyspark ml code into a gcp cluster?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, pyspark, cluster-computing

I want to run a pyspark ml project (boosting trees) into a google gloud cluster to compare the accuracy and the speed with a scikit learn same model. My code is ready but i don't know how to run it into a cluster. Thanks!!!

Comment: What have you done so far? Did you run your code in a local environment?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need is a Dataproc cluster. After creating a cluster, you can use any of the options listed in the official documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/guides/submit-job). But I would suggest one of the 2 options below.

1. Use `gcloud dataproc jobs submit pyspark`. See details [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/dataproc/jobs/submit/pyspark)
2. Submit a job through Dataproc console. A detailed example is [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/step-by-step-tutorial-pyspark-sentiment-analysis-on-google-dataproc-fef9bef46468)